# How to join values of two tables. python django

Tags: django, object, django-models, django-views, datatables

I am trying to use two tables inside one django query. But my query is resulting as "invalid JSON" format.

I want to filter data in Request table by (status="Aprv"). The Request table contains attributes **'from_id'** and **'to_id'**.

The uid is the id of the user who is currently logged in.

If the **current user(uid)** is having the **'from_id'** of **Requests** table,
the query should return data of **'to_id'** from the 'RegUsers' table.

If the **current user(uid)** is having the **'to_id'** of **Requests** table,
the query should return data of **'from_id'** from the 'RegUsers' table.

class frnds(APIView):

```
  def post(self, request):

    uid = request.data['uid']
    ob = Requests.objects.filter(status="Aprv")
    fid = ob.value('from_id')
    tid = ob.value('to_id')
    if fid == uid:
        obj = RegUsers.objects.filter(u_id=tid)
    else:
        obj = RegUsers.objects.filter(u_id=fid)
    ser = android_serialiser(obj, many=True)                       
    return Response(ser.data)
```

Please Do Help me Currect the syntax.

Comment: You can try the `.select_related()` method.  See docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related.  There's also `.union()`, but that would require two separate queries `>>> qs1.union(qs2, qs3)`

Comment: @ja408 can you edit my code please?

Comment: and I don't use foreign keys.